# Clear Symfony Cache on IIS

Tags: caching, iis, symfony

I'am running Symfony on a IIS Server on Windows Web Server 2008 with an MSQL Database.

I gave the webserver full permission to write the cache and logs directories. But when I clear the cache via console command it says

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug

Der Befehl "stty" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.

[RuntimeException]

Unable to write in the "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LocalUser\client_transparency.stage\app/cache/dev_new" directory
cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers]
```

I even stopped the IIS and tried it again and but the same error occured.

And another problem, is that I sometimes just have a blank page in the frontend in production mode.

Comment: What if you run a command as an administrator and run again `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug`?

Answer (score 0):

When you run symfony command line it use your local account, check if user under which you are logged has permissions to read write.

IIs is always runned as other user, depends how you configure it

Answer (score 0):

In order to run administrator-only applications, I have to open the command line in this relatively laborious way:

- Press Win, type "cmd"
- Wait for the menu to populate
- Lift hand off the keyboard and put it on the mouse
- Right click the "cmd.exe" menu item
- Choose "Run as administrator"
- In th project directory path run the command: php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug